# Public action method "actionMethod" not found in Controller "controller"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an admin area in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project.
After add Authorize attribute in Index action of Home controller in admin area (localhost/admin/), when I redirected to /Account/Login I get an error saying that ObjetivosSubMenu was not found in AccountController, the problem is that action is in my _Layout.cshtml file (@Html.Action("ObjetivosSubMenu")) and Login.cshtml file do not point to this layout.

Index action in HomeController in admin area:

```
// GET: /Admin/Home/
        [Authorize(Users = "admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Specify the area in `@Html.Action()` e.g. `@Html.Action("ObjetivosSubMenu", "MyController", new { area = "admin" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke This action is not in admin area. When I get redirected to Account/Login, the error says that this action dont exist in Account controller, and in fact, not exist, this action is in HomeController of base URL. The strange thing is _Login.cshtml (Account/Login) does not point to _Layout.cshtml wich is pointed by Index action of HomeController (not the same of admin area)

Comment: Then `@Html.Action("ObjetivosSubMenu", "MyController", new { area = "" })`

Comment: Seems that just adding the controller is sufficient: @Html.Action("ObjetivosSubMenu", "Home"), now is working, and I figured out that Login.cshtml was using the layout defined in the _ViewStart.cshtml.

Comment: No problem - you didn't say which (if any) area the `ObjetivosSubMenu` was in which is why I made the comment